# Asp.net MVC 3 Remote Validation Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, unobtrusive-validation, jquery-validate

Every time remote validation fires on my form, I get the following url...not what I expected:
http://localhost:13927/Validation/ValidateAnswer?%5B0%5D.Episodes%5B0%5D.Questions%5B0%5D.Answers%5B0%5D.AnswerText=undefined&%5B0%5D.Episodes%5B0%5D.Questions%5B0%5D.Answers%5B0%5D.Id=undefined

The controller is correct.  The action is correct, but the parameters are not what I expected.  Any ideas as to how I can correct this?  The signature for the validation action is `public JsonResult ValidateAnswer(string answerText, int id).`

Here is the Model:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an answer.")]
    [Remote("ValidateAnswer", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("/", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id="frm"}))
    {
        for (var p = 0; p < Model.Count; p++)
        {
            <div class="hidden questions" id="@Model[p].Id">
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model[p].Episodes.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="even" style="margin-top: 15px; padding: 15px;">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model[p].Episodes[i])
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        }
    }
```

Here is the Editor Referenced:

```
<h3 style="margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;">@Model.EpisodeType, which started on @Model.StartDate and ended on @Model.EndDate</h3>
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id)
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++ )
{
    <p style="margin: 0; margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em">@Model.Questions[i].QuestionText</span><br/>
    </p>
    <p style="margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        @{ var theClass = string.Concat("autocomplete", Model.Questions[i].IsYesNo ? "yesno" : Model.Questions[i].IsTime ? "time" : ""); }
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Questions[i].Answers[0].AnswerText, new {@class=theClass, question=Model.Questions[i].Id.ToString()})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Questions[i].Answers[0].AnswerText)        
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Questions[i].Id)
    </p>
}
```

Comment: There will be multiple AJAX requests sent for each input field. Are you sure that's what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Ultimately, I traced it back to line 309 in jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:

```
return $(options.form).find(":input[name='" + paramName + "']").val();
```

This jQuery call returns 0 objects, possibly because the name it's filtering for (your input name) contains square brackets, which confuse the jQuery parser.

You can fix it by replacing it with this line:

```
return $(options.form).find(":input[id='" + options.element.id + "']").val();
```

The above is filtering by id, so no weird characters to trip up jQuery.